# How to proper perform live using all my scenes from my projects?

Tags: performing, ableton-live, live-sound

I was wondering if anyone can point me to some tutorials or courses (maybe no more than 100 dollars or around that), that can teach me how to setup a live performance. Like everybody when I make a new song I create a new project, inside my project my song is made up by different scenes whit different plugins and different instruments. I want to learn how to take all of my scenes from all my projects and perform them live inside a single project. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You might be looking for how to export and import "stems". In any case, there has to be some planning and systematic naming and organization, and you'll have to prepare each individual song manually one-by-one to be compatible with each other. Software cannot automatically figure out how things are organized in your songs and how they should be combined together. You have to follow rules and conventions. I don't do much live "DJ" stuff, but when I do, I export at most 8 grouped WAV audio tracks/stems from each part of each song, and import them all in one big session. But it has to be planned.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replay..how about this approach?
https://forum.ableton.com/viewtopic.php?t=195844

Answer (score 1):

I think the key to your question is in "different instruments and different VSTs"

In Ableton, when you create a track, and it's a MIDI track, you assign an instrument. Now all the MIDI clips in that track will be played by that instrument.

This means, at minimum, your "mega-project" will need one track for **each instrument** of **each song**. That can add up pretty fast. But nobody's going to stop you from trying to run a 300-track project live. I just wouldn't expect good things to happen during it.

With that many active tracks/instruments/VSTs you're almost certain to run into audio buffer issues and stuttering. And even if you have god-like amounts of RAM to handle any buffer issues that could arise, that's not factoring for the *human memory* aspect of remembering *where the heck that one guitar sound is* in a mess of 300 tracks.

The FAR superior (but less customizable) option is, as pointed out in comments, to bounce each track out to audio, then you can import each song as its own clip on an audio track, and your live performance can trigger those clips. You won't be able to edit the instruments and VSTs live, but there are other DJ techniques you can do while playing the clips live, like 3-band EQ if you want to mix the low end of one track with the high end of another.